# php <br> before var_dump not producing line break

Tags: php, class, line-breaks, var-dump

I have written php script as follows but the line break used before var_dump function is not producing a line break before giving bool(true). Please help me in find what mistake I am doing.

```
<?php
class Fruit {
}
$apple = new Fruit();
echo "<br>" . var_dump($apple instanceof Fruit) . "<br>";
?>
```

Output:
`bool(true)`

No line break before bool(true)

Comment: [`var_dump`](https://www.php.net/var_dump) dumps immediately to the screen, it will not append to the echo. Break it into 3 full statements instead.

Comment: `var_dump` does not _return_ a value, yet you are trying to _concatenate_ its return value into a string. What happens is that var_dump writes to the output buffer first, and only afterwards your string value is echo'd to the output buffer.

Comment: Try `var_export($apple instanceof Fruit, true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using <br> for the output and splitting it into 3 complete statements (as suggested in the comment), it is better to use <pre>.

```
class Fruit {
  public $prop = 1;
}
$apple = new Fruit();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($apple instanceof Fruit,$apple);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
object(Fruit)#2 (1) {
  ["prop"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

With  the line breaks which are contained in the var_dump output are processed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
echo "<pre>"; echo var_dump($apple); echo "</pre>";
```

Technically @aynber and @CBroe are right.